# Show that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{a+(k+(1-x))^2}\:{\rm d}k\le\frac1{\sqrt a}\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt a}{1-x}}\frac1{1+y^2}\:{\rm d}y$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, inequality, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

Let $a>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. How do we see that $$\int_0^\infty\frac1{a+(k+(1-x))^2}\:{\rm d}k\le\frac1{\sqrt a}\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt a}{1-x}}\frac1{1+y^2}\:{\rm d}y.?$$ This should be just an application of the substitution rule, but I can't figure out how we need to substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$k+1-x=\sqrt{a}t$$
$$\Rightarrow dk=\sqrt{a}dt $$
$$\implies \int_0^\infty\frac{dk}{a+(k+1-x)^2}=\int_\frac{1-x}{\sqrt a}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a dt}{a(1+t^2)}$$

Now apply reciprocal substitution, $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and you are done.

**CAVEAT**

$1-x$ may be negative, break the integral in that case.